struct Foo { uint8_t _x[0]; }; versus struct Foo; for C opaque pointers: is there a meaningful difference?
In the section on opaque structs in the Rustonomicon, it provides the following example of opaque structs in C:
struct Foo; /* Foo is a structure, but its contents are not part of the public interface */
struct Bar;
void foo(struct Foo *arg);
void bar(struct Bar *arg);

It says an opaque Foo for use over FFI can be defined in Rust like this:
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    _data: [u8; 0],
    _marker:
        core::marker::PhantomData<(*mut u8, core::marker::PhantomPinned)>,
}

However, when I try creating C bindings using this example using cbindgen, the generated C header has this struct definition:
typedef struct Foo {
  uint8_t _data[0];
} Foo;

This has the unfortunate disadvantage that C code can now do something like foo._data. But other than this, is there any issue that could be caused by cbindgen generating this struct definition, rather than generating just typedef struct Foo Foo;?

It turns out there is a difference, as ISO C does not allow zero-size arrays, at least according to GCC (source).

See also C11 §6.7.6.2 Array declarators ¶1: In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.   You'll find similar wording in other versions of the standard.

Zero sized arrays is an obsolete gcc extension predating standardized flexible array members.

I discovered that cbindgen generates a proper opaque struct if #[repr(C)] is removed.
I.e.,
pub struct Foo {
    _data: [u8; 0],
    _marker:
        core::marker::PhantomData<(*mut u8, core::marker::PhantomPinned)>,
}

becomes typedef struct Foo Foo; in the generated C header.
In fact, it is not even necessary to use the _data and _marker trick if you want your Rust struct to store meaningful data. You can just store your native Rust data in the struct, and the struct will be an opaque struct in the generated C header.
